# Support multi functionality in server.js

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, express.js

i've node app that having the main function server.js(entry point)

Following is the server.js file code

```
var childModule = require("./controller/childModule");
var server = http.createServer(app);
var proxy= require('./controller/proxy');
var proc = require('./controller/runIntProcess');
var extLoader = require("./controller/extLoader");
....


var server = module.exports = {};

server.run = function () {
    proc.pre(function () {
        server.listen(app.get('port'), function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log('application Listening on port: ' + app.get('port'));
            }
            proxy.web(server);
        });
    })
};



server.addNewFunctionlity= function(oDir){
    extLoader.load(oDir.folder);
};

module.exports = function () {
    server.run();
}();

server.childModule = childModule;
```

The code do this:

when user call to the server he need to write the following code

```
var myModule = require("myModule");
myModule.addNewFunctionlity({folderPath:__dirname + '/files'});
myModule.addNewFunctionlity({folderPath:__dirname + '/files2'});
```

**The Code is working!** but I've several questions :-)

1. Does I export the childModule OK?
2. Does the usage of my API is make sense?
3. Does the var `server = module.exports = {}` is OK?

The code is running a node app which can be cousume by CMD (call to the server.js) without any args or using it by code.
in addition I need to expose some API's like childModule

Comment: What is `proxy`, `procInv` and `extLoader`?

Comment: please provide some brief context about the code or have commenting properly.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - done , does it help?

Comment: @Neel - done , is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't pass file folders/files to a fn like that, I'd rather pass the functionality subject like:

```
myModule.addNewFunctionlity('geoMapping');
myModule.addNewFunctionlity('cookieService');
```

then refactor you fn nomenclature, maybe

```
myModule.addNewFunctionlity('geo.geoMapping');
myModule.addNewFunctionlity('frontend.cookieService');
```

If you think you really need to setup file/folder structure, then apply maybe a `setupPath()` fn:

```
myModule.setupPath({ folderPath:__dirname + '/files2'} );
```

so that in 5-7 years you and others will understand at a glance what 
`addNewFunctionlity()` and `setupPath()` is about :)